# how to display woocommerce price filter , average rating filter outside sidebar widgets?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce, price

I want to use some widgets outside sidebar. is there any functions  or hooks to do that ?

I know how to use actions, but I don't know what actions to use.

```
add_action( 'action_name', 'your_function_name' );

function your_function_name() {
// Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use plugins for this? try this plugin, it might cover all you need.
[Woocoomerce Products Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/)

Comment: Thanks, But I'm not looking for a plugin. I'm customizing my theme and I need to use average rating filter and price filter in header.

Answer (score 0):

If your wanting to use Widgets you need to have a place to load them such as a sidebar. Good news is that you can register your own widget location.

Go to your functions.php of your child theme

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Top Area',
        'id'            => 'toparea',
        'description'   => 'top area custom widget',
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
```

Now go to your content template and call for

```
<?php
  if(is_active_sidebar('toparea')){
   dynamic_sidebar('toparea');
  }
?>
```

Now load all of the desired widgets in the toparea widget container from the widget or customizer menu